# dynamic from address - postmark

Tags: php, postmark

I'm using Postmark to send emails. I want to be able to use if for a send to a friend form so I need the from email address to appear to be from a specific sender. It looks like Postmark only allows you to send from the address specified in the signature. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

Alex here from the Postmark team. We can enable dynamic sender signatures in your account for approved usage. Drop our support staff a note, support@postmarkapp.com, and we can enable that feature for you.

The reason for this restriction is to help reduce the likelihood of spam complaints, part of our system that we carefully manage to keep deliverability high for everyone. In your particular use case, depending on how you design your feature, it is possible that someone could start using your form to send spam.

Additionally, by not having a specific sender signature, your emails fall back to our email signing instead of your own - this may impact your delivery rates. For optimal delivery, we recommend having the "from" be a real email address that the account owner can access, and use your users' name as the "name" attribute and their email in the reply-to.

That's not always possible, though, so we can manually enable the dynamic from address feature on request. Just know that delivery rates *may* be impacted and if the form begins generating significant spam complaints, we may contact you to request that you make changes to your system.